# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I tried this code, but I got the following error, I tried searching and implementing for solutions, but none of them worked.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(100,1)))
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
```

Error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Comment: Hi! not replicating in Keras 2.6 .please find below gist for reference .  https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/a2d22766d081fffbfe7dab44a94472b3/github_.ipynb